# Checking whether a value is of type Vector via pattern matching

Tags: scala, design-patterns, types, matching

I need to make a match statement that checks whether the value is Vector or not. The type of elements may differ, I just need to make a case when the input is a Vector. I write the code like this:

```
symbValue match {
        ......
        case symbValue: Vector[_] => symbValue.foldleft("")((acc, value) => ....)
        ......
```

I get the compilation error:

```
value foldleft is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Vector[_]
```

How can this type of pattern matching be done? Can it even be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capital "L" for `foldLeft`. Your code works fine, barring the typo.

Comment: I think its just one of those days. Thanks!